# Excel VBA error overflow

Tags: vba, excel

I have a program to solve packing problem 3D. When I run the program with only 100 rows of data my code works, but when I use all my data I have an error:

> Run-time error '6':
>
> Overflow

[image: Image version]

Here is my code:

```
If rotationtype = 2 Then
    Do While Worksheets(6).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Value <> ""
        ' 0,1 > inputan
        If Worksheets(6).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Offset(0, 1).Value > Worksheets(6).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Value Then
            Worksheets(6).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Offset(0, 3).Value = Worksheets(6).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Offset(0, 1).Value
            Worksheets(6).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Offset(0, 4).Value = Worksheets(6).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Value
            Worksheets(6).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Offset(0, 5).Value = Worksheets(6).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Offset(0, 2).Value
        Else ' 0,1 < inputan
            Worksheets(6).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Offset(0, 3).Value = Worksheets(6).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Value
            Worksheets(6).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Offset(0, 4).Value = Worksheets(6).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Offset(0, 1).Value
            Worksheets(6).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Offset(0, 5).Value = Worksheets(6).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Offset(0, 2).Value
        End If
        xrow = xrow + 1
    Loop
    Toplamkutusayisi = xrow - 2
    xrow = 2
Else
```

I have 49,606 rows of data:

[image]

How can I avoid getting this error?

Comment: could you click "Debug" when the error appears and then check the value of xrow by entering "? xrow" in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G)

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare your variables? Soudns like an integer overflow with xrow.

Just add

```
Dim xrow as long
```

at the beginning of your Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, I assume that the problem is in the `Worksheets(6)` part.

Do you have 7 work-sheets? Remember: counting starts at 0! Not at 1!

If this is the case, change the index to 7 instead of 6:

```
 Worksheets(7).Cells(xrow, xcolumn).Value
```